# jQuery : width & height attribute value of <embed> tag on load

Tags: jquery, html

I have an embed tag.

```
<embed id="embed1" src="test.mp4" width="320" height="260" ></embed>
```

How to change the width & height attribute of `<embed>` tag on load using JavaScript / jQuery ? I know how to set the attribute value by the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#embed1').attr('width', '320');
});
```

I can set the width to 100%, but what will be the value of height attribute?

```
<embed id="embed1" src="test.mp4" width="100%" height="?" ></embed>
```

I wish I can omit the height attribute, or set it to auto .

**Note**: Given that I can't use HTML5 `<video>` tag as I have to backward support older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) function instead of using [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the width and height.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  embed1 = $('#embed1');
  embed1.width(320);
  embed1.height(embed1.width(320));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* omit the height attribute, like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#embed1').attr('width', '320').removeAttr("height");
});
```

I don't know what the outcome of that will be, but at least you know now you can do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to keep the aspect ratio wouldn't it be:

```
var embed = $('#embed1');
var ar = embed.width()/embed.height(); 
embed.attr('width', '100%'); 
embed.attr('height', embed.width()/ar);
```

Answer (score 0):

should be like this :

```
$("#embed1").css({ 'width' : '320' });
```